# Combine Python Pandas dataframe rows with addition

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe, date-range

I'm struggling with this. I've tried searching and have tried a few options but can't quite seem to manage it.

I want to take the following dataframe (simplified), which has a date_range as an index with 30 minute intervals:

```
                     Data
2016-11-24 00:00:00   5
2016-11-24 00:30:00   1
2016-11-24 01:00:00   4
2016-11-24 01:30:00   11
2016-11-24 02:00:00   3
2016-11-24 02:30:00   19
etc
```

And essentially "combine" the rows, adding the values together and changing the time series to hourly rather than 30 minute intervals, so that I end up with the following:

```
                     Data
2016-11-24 00:00:00   6
2016-11-24 01:00:00   15
2016-11-24 02:00:00   22
etc
```

Does anyone have any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with `sum`:

```
df = df.resample('h').sum()
print (df)
                     Data
2016-11-24 00:00:00     6
2016-11-24 01:00:00    15
2016-11-24 02:00:00    22
```

Comment: Wow. That was a speedy response, and that works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Glad can help you!